# Complex FROM condition for Gmail messages

Tags: email, search, google-apps-script, gmail, conditional-statements

I have to move to SPAM Gmail messages according to the following complex query based on sender field:

```
var qyr = '{from:(*@mail.ru -sender1@mail.ru -sender2@mail.ru -sender3@mail.ru )' + 
          ' from:(*@yandex.ru)}';
var threads = GmailApp.search(query=qyr, start=0, max=500)
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
  GmailApp.moveThreadToSpam(threads[i]);
}
```

But this code doesn't work as it should.
 If I leave only first line (with *mail.ru*) or second line (with *yandex.ru*) alone it works fine. When I combine them both it fetches only *mail.ru* messages. 
According to [operator manual](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) if I want to make logical `OR` I should explcitly put `OR` or set two `FROM` inside braces. The variant with direct `OR` **doesn't work** either. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the query work in the gmail web interface?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach, yes, it works. Maybe concatenation is the reason? However, I follow the [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out the problem with the help of Apps Scripts issue tracker guys.
I was missing ***spaces*** in my concatenation. Also, switching to single `from` clause makes the query more concise.

The correct form of the above statement should be alike:

```
var qyr = '{from: ' + 
        ' ((@mail.ru ' +
        ' -sender1@mail.ru -sender2@mail.ru -sender3@mail.ru) ' + 
        ' OR ' +
        ' (@yandex.ru -sender1@yandex.ru) ' +
        ' )} ';
```